# Prove that $1 - \sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}\cdot t \leq (1-t^2)^n$ for $n \geq 4$ and $t \in [0, 1]$

Tags: calculus, inequality

For the context, see: [Prove $|1 - (1+\frac{z-1}{n})^m| \leq 1$ where $|z|\leq 1$ and $m<n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4451523/prove-1-1-fracz-1nm-leq-1-where-z-leq-1-and-mn)

I drawed some graphs for small $n$, it should be true:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WLOG, assume that $1 - \sqrt{n/2}\, t \ge 0.$

Using Bernoulli inequality $(1 - v)^s \ge 1 - sv$ for all $0 \le v < 1$ and $s\ge 1$, we have
$$(1 - t^2)^{n/4} \ge 1 - t^2n/4 \ge 0.$$

It suffices to prove that
$$1 - \sqrt{n/2}\, t \le (1 - t^2n/4)^4.$$

Letting $t^2n/2 = u^2$, it suffices to prove that, for all $u \in [0, 1]$,
$$1 - u \le (1 - u^2/2)^4$$
or
$$\frac{1}{16}u(u^7 - 8u^5 + 24u^3 - 32u + 16) \ge 0.$$

It suffices to prove that, for all $u\in (0, 1]$,
$$u^7 - 8u^5 + 24u^3 - 32u + 16 \ge 0$$
or
$$(1 - u)^3(-u^4 - 3u^3 + 2u^2 + 14u + 9) + 13(u - 19/26)^2 + 3/52 \ge 0$$
which is clearly true.

We are done.

Comment: That "which is true" is not immediately obvious to me.

Comment: @martycohen Thanks for comment. I will update it soon.

Comment: Remembering that u is from 0 to 1 makes the new explanation very clear.

Comment: @martycohen Yes, thanks.